# Laravel Nova + Laravel Jetstream Login Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-nova, laravel-authentication

If I login to Nova, sign out and then sign into our client facing side (/login) I get a modal that pops up with a 404 error. This modal error happens on /login and does not redirect to the dashboard.  I can then manually navigate to the dashboard I will be logged in properly.

I'm wondering if this is from the session cookie and how I can fix this conflict between nova and jetstream.

Comment: you need to share more detail on the implementation of your modal what you are doing it and when does it show and assumed you have nova and jetstream installed

Comment: What's your dashboard route?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the modal showing nova.... . so to solve this problem, I had to force the reload of the page by adding this. `window.location.href = window.location.href` in the jetstream Login. vue (ressources/js/pages/Auth/Login.vue ) .

```
methods: {
           submit() {
               this.form
                   .transform(data => ({
                       ... data,
                       remember: this.form.remember ? 'on' : ''
                   }))
                   .post(this.route('login'), {
                       onFinish: () =>{
                               this.form.reset('password');
                               window.location.href = window.location.href;
                       },
                   })

           }
       }
```